# "This browser does not support frames."

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Python + Selenium to interact with a webpage with frameset and frames.

However, I get this error when I do something like `print driver.page_source`:

```
<frameset cols="*" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="118,*" frameborder="0" onbeforeunload="unload()">
    <frame src="/xxx/frameset/xxx.html" name="ENTETE_WIN" id="ENTETE_WIN" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
    <frame src="/xxx/frameset/bodyFrame.html" name="BODY_WIN" id="BODY_WIN" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
    <noframes>
        &lt;body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"&gt;
        This browser does not support frames.
        &lt;/body&gt;
  </noframes>
</frameset>
```

My selenium version is 2.53.2. I tried with Firefox and Chrome with driver 2.21.

Comment: What browser are you using, version, etc. Please provide more details.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Sorry, I am editing my question, but it was accidentally posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are not getting any error. What `driver.page_source` shows you is an actual HTML of the page. In your case, the page contains 2 frames, as well as additional section called `<noframes>`, which the end-user would see if their browser did not support frames. So what you see is not an error targeted at you.

I suggest for your automation, ignore the entire `<noframes>` section all together. Only very very old browsers (e.g. IE 2) do not support frames (see detailed explanation on frames [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_frames.htm)).

Now if I understand correctly, your trouble is that you cannot select any elements, because your elements are in frames. Well, Selenium provides whole set of functions to deal with frames. See [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html?highlight=frame#moving-between-windows-and-frames) for Selenium on Python.

So before selecting any other elements, you need to select and switch to corresponding frame. For example:

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to_frame("ENTETE_WIN")
```

will switch you to the left frame (the first statement makes sure you are on "main" window to begin with). Or

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
driver.switch_to_frame("BODY_WIN")
```

to switch to the right frame.

All other HTML elements are inside those frames, so you can select them using normal xpath, css and other selectors.